# column does not exist when it does

Tags: postgresql

using PGAdmin
queries:

```
SELECT * FROM analyzed_users;
SELECT * FROM time_table;
```

runs successfully. But query:

```
SELECT * FROM analyzed_users, time_table WHERE analyzed_users.id = time_table.userId
```

returns error:

> ERROR:  column analyzed_users.id does not exist
>   LINE 2: SELECT * FROM analyzed_users, time_table WHERE analyzed_user...
>   ********** Error **********
>   ERROR: column analyzed_users.id does not exist
>   SQL state: 42703
>   Character: 49

I'm struggling with it for a while and I have no idea why it doesn't want to work..

Comment: Could you post a schema snippet? Maybe we can try to reproduce with that.

Comment: are you sure the second query doesn't just have a typo in the column name?

Comment: Yeah it was wrong column name... The error was confusing for me because error tick was showing on table not on column. You should post it as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the WHERE clause in the second query:

```
WHERE analyzed_users.id = time_table.userId
```

The error is saying that `analyzed_users.id` doesn't exist in that table.

Check for and use the actual name of the column in `analyzed_users` that you want to compare to  `time_table.userId` in the second query. That should fix the problem.